# Срочно нужна помощь по sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Большая просьба, помочь!
Я только недавно начал изучать sql. Установил Microsoft Sql 2019. Импортирую туда таблицу csv для анализа. Импорт проходит успешно, но в итоге в таблице знаки вопроса вместо кириллицы, кирилица в верхней строке отображается корректно. Я пробовал менять кодировку в csv, не помогает. я пробовал импорт тестового csv с кириллицей, также вопросительные знаки. Мне нужно что-то настроить в самом sql?

Comment: Да, в самом `sql` у таблицы какой коллейшен и какой тип у столбца, куда вы грузите кириллицу? Там должен быть `nvarchar` либо `text`. Если просто `varchar`, то кириллица туда не помещается.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, был varchar, поменял на nvarchar, сохранил изменения, в новом запросе все также знаки вопроса

Comment: Коллейшен это параметры сортировки? стоит Cyrillic_General_CI_AS

Comment: Дальше не знаю чем помочь. Но вообще поиском тут поищите, что-то должно найтись.

Comment: Как вы думаете, кого-то волнует, изучаете вы sql недавно или уже много лет? Уберите из текста вопроса мольбы о помощи и т. п. Поместите в заголовок суть вопроса.

Comment: Как именно делаете импорт данных? Приведите код или точную последовательность действий.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте следующее концептуальное решение, основанное на `BULK LOAD`.

**cznames.txt**

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Вася |
| 2 | Петя |

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.myNameTable;

CREATE TABLE dbo.myNameTable(
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  NAME NVARCHAR(50) collate Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AS
);

BULK INSERT dbo.myNameTable 
FROM  'e:\Temp\cznames.txt'
WITH 
(
   FIRSTROW = 2,
   FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A',
   CODEPAGE = '65001'   -- is a must for the Cyrillic characters (UTF-8)
);

SELECT * FROM dbo.myNameTable;

-- just to see
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()
WHERE name LIKE 'Cyrillic%';
```

Answer (score -1):

У вас проблема в кодировке таблицы скорее всего. Вот тут с картинками объясняют, как выбрать правильную кодировку:

[Import CSV File Into SQL Server Using SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-sql-server-management-studio/)

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).